# Scikit-learn - how to use MinMaxScaler on new data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, minmax

I have created a linear regression Scikit-learn model for forex data. The model uses 60+ features, which are trading indicators derived from Open, High, Low, and Close (OHLC) data - which I get from API.

Before fitting the data into the model, I normalize it using [MinMaxScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html) (All the 60 + features). The model is saved as a Pickle.

Now, I am the following issue, and need help:

When I get the new OHLC data, I call previous 30 OHLC data points as well (as some of the indicators (features) are moving averages with 14-30 period intervals) and generate the 60+ features.

**However, I do not know how to scale those features - as per the previously calculated range of MinMaxScaler.** Any guidance will be highly appreciated. TIA

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Are you having trouble loading the saved `MinMaxScaler` object?

Comment: Have you tried [`minmax_scale`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.minmax_scale.html#sklearn.preprocessing.minmax_scale)? I think you can achieve your desired output and its usage is pretty straightforward.